# How to create a button adds 1 to a result that shown in a paragraph tag?

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I'm trying to create a small game and i need to create a button that adds 1 every time two variables are equal to each other, i have a paragraph tag which the result will be shown in it as a number. how to create that button to add 1 every time the two variables are equal ?

```
document.getElementById("rockbtn").onclick = function() {
    var x = 1;
    var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1)
        
    if (x == y) {
                    
        // the statement ?
                    
    } else { 
        alert("try again")
    }
}
```

Comment: you must post minimal, relevant code else your question will likely get closed down, unanswered.

Comment: Use `addEventListener()` to assign a function to run when you click on the button. The function should use `innerText` and `parseInt()` to read the contents of the tag and convert it to a number. Then it can add 1 and assign it back to `innerText`.

Comment: you mean i should create third variable with parseInt() and add it to the function ??

Answer (score 0):

Give the paragraph element an id. When `x` is equal to `y` increment the the value in the element via `result.textContent++`:

```js
document.getElementById("rockbtn").addEventListener('click', function() {
  var x = 1;
  var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1)
  console.log("generated number: " + y);
  if (x == y) {
    result.textContent++;
  } else {
    alert("try again")
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="rockbtn">Generate</button>
<p id="result">0</p>
```